# How to determine the fastest metabolism ?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, glucose

Which is the fastest metabolism ? Fructose metabolism or Glucose metabolism

Comment: Can you please add some more details on what exactly do you mean by metabolism?

Comment: I meant Fructolysis and Glycolysis which is the fastest one ?

Comment: in vivo or in vitro? there are a lot of variables that affect metabolic flux in vivo - this is NOT a straightforward question.

Comment: @petersmith yah, but it was asked in our and semester paper.